# Saving multiple forms efficiently using Django's Form Wizad and the issue of missing list indexes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I'm using Django's Form Wizard in my app. There are five forms in total however only three or four can be submitted, as two of the forms can be skipped based on a particular condition or from the two one form can be skipped based on a particular condition.

Contents of the list returned by SessionWizardView's done method is as follows:

```
[<test.myapp.models.AForm object at 0x0177EC10>, <test.myapp.models.BForm object at 0x01796150>, <test.myapp.models.CForm object at 0x01796530>, <test.myapp.models.DForm object at 0x01796910>, <test.myapp.models.EForm object at 0x01333540>]
```

To save the forms I am doing the following:

```
a = form_list[0].save(commit=False)
a.save()

b = form_list[1].save(commit=False)
b.parent_id = a
b.save()

c = form_list[2].save(commit=False)
c.parent_id = a
c.save()

d = form_list[3].save(commit=False)
d.parent_id = a
d.save()

d = form_list[4].save(commit=False)
d.parent_id = a
d.save()
```

As you will be able to tell, if only four forms are submitted, the list index 4 is non-existance and I get the "list index out of range" error, like wise if only three forms are submitted the list index 3 and 4 are non-existance. My question is two fold; one how I can I overcome the issue of non-existant list indexes and two how can I make the code more efficient?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

um, you can iterate over your`form_list`using`for`statement.

Comment: Thanks, I did think that would be the most obvious way but just wanted to make sure!